# LINQ: How to get items from an inner list into one list?

Tags: c#, linq, list

Having the following classes (highly simplified):

```
public class Child
{
    public string Label;
    public int CategoryNumber;
    public int StorageId;
}

public class Parent
{
    public string Label;
    public List<Child> Children = new List<Child>();
}
```

And having the following data:

```
var parents = new List<Parent>();

var parent = new Parent() {Label="P1"};
parent.Children.Add(new Child() {Label="C1", CategoryNumber=1, StorageId=10});
parent.Children.Add(new Child() {Label="C2", CategoryNumber=2, StorageId=20});
parents.Add(parent);

parent = new Parent() {Label="P2"};
parent.Children.Add(new Child() {Label="C3", CategoryNumber=1, StorageId=10});
parent.Children.Add(new Child() {Label="C4", CategoryNumber=2, StorageId=30});
parents.Add(parent);

parent = new Parent() {Label="P3"};
parent.Children.Add(new Child() {Label="C5", CategoryNumber=3, StorageId=10});
parent.Children.Add(new Child() {Label="C6", CategoryNumber=2, StorageId=40});
parents.Add(parent);
```

Now, how would I get a list of children (with CategoryNumber=2) from the list of parents containing at least one child with CategoryNumber = 1 ?

I can do the following but it does not appear to be optimal:

```
var validParents = from p in parents
                   where p.Children.Any (c => c.CategoryNumber==1)
                   select p;
var selectedChildren = validParents.Select(p => from c in p.Children 
                                                where c.CategoryNumber == 2
                                                select c);
```

Here's what I get for selectedChildren:

- `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Child>>`

  - `IEnumerable<Child>`

    - C2 2 20
  - `IEnumerable<Child>`

    - C4 2 30

Is it possible to only have one flat list containing the two children elements instead of two sub-list? How would it translate in LINQ ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1028641/641833)'s answer is great; I'd just like to point out that you can in fact do this query using *query continuation syntax*:

```
from parent in parents 
where parent.Children.Any (c => c.CategoryNumber==1)
select parent into p
from child in p.Children
where child.CategoryNumber == 2
select child
```

Notice how **the "into" lets you pipe the result of one query into the next query**. Pretty slick, eh?

Comment: @Eric: Yeah, the LINQ query syntax for this is quite nice (and probably slightly better to use as opposed to mixing query and extension method syntax). Whenever I encounter this topic, I do however feel that LINQ is missing a concatenation operator (akin to Seq.concat in F#), which could be used as an alternative to SelectMany, and is indeed very handy in other cases. A simple overload of the Enumerable.Concat method that takes a IEnumerable<IEnuerable<T>> parameter would do the job quite well. Any thoughts (or even better, plans) regarding this?

Comment: Ah, it seems MoreLINQ does define this operator: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview. It would be quite nice to have in the BCL though (along with a few others such as Zip).

Answer (score 54):

You can string a couple queries together, using [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) and [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb910023.aspx).

```
var selectedChildren = (from p in parents
                       where p.Children.Any (c => c.CategoryNumber==1)
                       select p)
                       .SelectMany(p => p.Children)
                       .Where(c => c.CategoryNumber == 2);

// or...

var selectedChildren = parents
                         .Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.CategoryNumber == 1))
                         .SelectMany(p => p.Children)
                         .Where(c => c.CategoryNumber == 2);
```

Comment: Works great! SelectMany seems to be a useful method. Do you have any suggestion for a web site or a book about fully understanding Linq?

Comment: For sites, the one you're on is good - most of my linq problems have been solved with a quick search or posted question here.  the only book that i've looked at is this one...  http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft%C2%AE-PRO-Developer-Paolo-Pialorsi/dp/0735624003/ref=sr_1_23?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1245694305&sr=8-23